# After magento upgrade prices including tax are displayed as 0 on detail page

Tags: magento

I upgraded a magento store from 1.3.x to 1.7.0.0. This caused some bugs which I am fixing now.

I am stuck at this one: the price of products added after the upgrade are displayed correctly in the category page but not on the detail page. For some reason the price including tax on the detail page of a product added after the upgrade is always '0'. The price excluding tax is displayed correctly. You can see this here: http://www.stagefreaks.nl/gedore-scaffhamer.html

Furthermore: the price including and excluding tax is correct in the shoppingcart and during checkout.

Any idea what might cause this problem ? I turned of caching at the moment, so it is not a caching issue (and it has been an issue for over a week now).

Thank you very much for any reply.

Comment: have you tried to disable your custom theme and see if they are wrong with default template bundled with 1.7 ?

Comment: Yes I did. They are wrong in the default theme as well. Same situation.

Answer (score 1):

in order to solve a bug, the first step is to know where it comes from.
As you already have discarded a template issue, let's focus on the non-core code:

- rename app/code/local/ to app/code/local_backup/: this will disable all local modules. Reload your page and check if the price is still wrong.

  - if it's still wrong, rename app/code/community/ to app/code/community_backup/ and reload the product page
- when you've find out which code pool is responsible, undo the folder name's change and disable one module at a time (putting the tag `<active>` as false in the app/etc/modules/module.xml file or renaming the folder)

Once you know which module is responsible, you'll have to review it to see how it messes with your product detail view.

Oh, also, edit your index.php file to show errors:

- comment out the condition around `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true)`
- uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I'm getting closer. app/code/local_backup made the website crash: white page, nothing loaded. So I skipped to the community option, and found out that the community/Remerce folder is reponsible. If I uncomment this, the price is displayed correctly, but the page stops loading halfway. So no image and no product options etc are displayed. Apparently this module is somehow responsible for product questions, so I tried to remove the custom "productquestion" template directory, alas, to no avail.

Comment: @Digits so if you disable this module (change `true` to false in his `<active>` tag in his xml declaration file), does the price appears correctly? This extension has not been updated since Magento v1.2, and reading the comment it's not working in latest version. I'd strongly recomend to uninstall it.

Comment: That is correct. However, the bottom half of the page is missing then. Which is why I'm a bit afraid to uninstall the extension...

Comment: @Digits is there any log file in var/ directory? when looking at the source code (html) of the page? have you edited your index.php to show errors? can I see this behaviour somewhere?

Comment: The error was hidden in the grey background, this is it: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Mage_Productquestion_Helper_Data' not found in <b>XXXXXXXXX/app/Mage.php</b> on line <b>546</b><br />

Comment: @Digits what's on line 546 of app/Mage.php?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11028/discussion-between-osdave-and-digits)

Answer (score 1):

A Specific solution of this problem is....

This Error occur  if you install a new custom module and clear the magento cache.

magento creates the Helper,Model,Controller ,Adminahml on installation of your module.
From these files magento knows about your module.

For Ex.

I Create a module name as createform
Module folder is 
Createform/Newform/etc/
                  /Helper/Data.php
                  /controllers
                  /Model
                  /Block/Myform.php

After installation of this module, magento will create a file name as 
Createform_Newform_Helper_Data.php in /includes/src/  folder.

Note:- If this file not created in /includes/src/ folder.

Fatal error: Class 'Createform_Newform_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on 546
Then this error will occur.

For removing this error Manually create this file in includes/src folder.
Like:-
/includes/src/Createform_Newform_Helper_Data.php

and add code of Data.php file in Createform_Newform_Helper_Data.php file.

Then refresh your site.
This error is removed from your system and it works properly.

Also check your system.log file for other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch but could it have something to do with the new VAT options? There are options for vat calculation there you could check out.

Comment: I tried this first, but I haven't found an option that fixed this.